# Определить грамматическую основу предложения

Tags: синтаксис, основа

Как определить грамматическую основу предложения "Откуда тебе знать, правда или нет?" С первой частью,думаю, понятно - сказуемое "знать". А вот в придаточной где что?

Answer (score 2):

***Откуда тебе знать, правда или нет?***

1. Это сложноподчиненное предложение (СПП) с  придаточным изъяснительным, упрощенный разговорный вариант.

Главное предложение (1) – безличное, инфинитивное. Главный член выражен независимым инфинитивом «знать». Придаточное предложение (2) неполное, речь там идет об информации, которая определяется из контекста, поэтому ее  можно условно заменить местоимением «это».
*Откуда тебе знать, правда **(это)** или нет?*

Тогда «правда или нет» – это составное именное сказуемое, однородные отношения между именными частями, разделительный союз ИЛИ.

В СПП такого вида в качестве союза используется частица ЛИ: Откуда тебе знать,  правда ли это или нет.

Но в  разговорном варианте мы видим **упрощенную структуру.**

**О вопросительном знаке в СПП:**  http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88

4. Вопросительный знак ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточной: Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия?

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! (Я думала так же, но сомневалась...)

Comment: Пожалуйста, меня  очень радует, что  наши мнения совпали.

Comment: Меня тоже... Еще раз - огромное спасибо!